# How do I get MailCore to work correctly?

Tags: xcode, email, macos

I'm trying to build MailCore into my app but I keep getting

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTCoreAccount", referenced from:
```

That is the only error I'm getting and `CTCoreAccount` is in the project.

Comment: how did you include MailCore - as a static library?

Comment: No, I got the entire source code into my app because the static library wouldn't work; It would give me the same error

Comment: use remail available on google svn.

Comment: I started a fresh project with MailCore added via the site's step guide. It worked. I uploaded to git, downloaded, re-linked MailCore and suddenly it's not finding any libraries, same error as you. Will mess with paths and get back with an answer if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use mail core framework, visit the  [link](http://libmailcore.com) follow step by step process and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer. It is not "The Answer" but I have an answer and it worked.

Eidt: For this: After a slew of issues, I've realized that "this" particular fix is that you need to add libmailcore.a to the frameworks. It keeeps getting deleted by XCode, or you may ahve added the MailCore Framework instead.

Started a fresh project, erased everything by removing application files to trash, then deleting references. "Added" via group (unsure if it matters) all my folers/files from the project I was trying to.

Had to tell it where the pch and Info.plist were, (essentially pointing it to my old project). Re-added all frameworks, and voila, it compiled.

I'm suspecting XCode 4.5 has different framework settings as far as library paths and valid flags for linker, etc. But nothing I tried regarding that fixed it. I would love to do this more direclty, old project is on 4.3, and won't be upgrading it if this is happening. Anyway, up and running, hope others are soon too. Would like real answer myself